# How to fix broken QGIS project when folders structure has changed

Tags: qgis, data-source

The folder structures for our network was changed the middle of the night without consulting me.  Usually if a shapefile moves location, QGIS will bring up a broken layers dialogue box for me to fix.  Instead, for some projects, I can see the layers in the layer panel, but the status bar pulsates green with nothing happening.  Other projects take a long time to open but eventually they do.  Can someone help me understand what's happening and how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

You can open QGIS project file (*.qgs) in text editor and fix broken paths using find & replace tool. The QGIS project file is xml document.
Here it is na example:

[image]